# Restriction of s3 bucket access using a role is not working

Tags: amazon-s3

I have been trying to restrict `s3bucket` access for an account.
Created `IAM` user with no permissions included.
Created a role and added trust to the AWS user.
Tested the assume role capability via aws `cli` in powershell, which uses sts token and the access is successful.
Tried `get-s3bucket` from `cli`, which gave access denied error, as permissions were not attached to the role.
Provided default s3read permission to the IAM role.
Tried `get-s3bucket` and it returned all `s3 bucket`.

Now, I have to restrict the account to get and put objects in one bucket.Created below json policy, but it shows access denied error.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also tried to upload a file to the specific `s3bucket` via `awscli`, which gives `PutObject` operation :access denied error.

I am expecting to add permission to the IAM role, which has the trust relationship to the `IAM` user.
Role should have permission attached to only give get and put operation on a single bucket.

Comment: Setup seems correct there is some other issue in bucket or the user.

Comment: Thanks Piyush for the comment.
I havent defined any permission for the user or any bucket policy.
I am defining the below Credential to assume the role, which has permission fors3 operation.
$Creds = (Use-STSRole -RoleArn "arn of role" -RoleSessionName "role name").Credentials

Comment: I think, when I perform a copy command, its using my default profile, and utilizing the access/secret key configured for IAM user, which donot have permissions..
I tried adding a profile with the temp token generated by sts, and it gives me error stating The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

I am looking for the powershell command, to use the sts token generated during the role assumption , so that the permissions are aligned for the s3 operations.

Comment: I have already edited the config file and added the profile detail below to use assumed role:
[profile assumerole]
role_arn = role arn
source_profile = user1

I am trying to see, how can I use this profile, while performing a s3 copy operation via powershell.